# Autocomplete with Ehcache

Tags: java, autocomplete, ehcache

I have several autocomplete fields within a form I'm developing. My largest containing nearly 20k records and the smallest containing around 1k. Up until now I've just used a TreeMap to handle this task, however I'm finding it to be very in efficient.  My current structure looked like this.

```
private SortedMap<String, Set<String>> cache;

public AutocompleteCacheServiceImpl() {
    cache = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<String, Set<String>>());
}
```

while being populated like so,

```
private void populateCache(String id, String name) {
    int len = name.length();

    for (int i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        String key = name.substring(0, i).toLowerCase();
        if(this.cache.containsKey(key)) {
            Set<String> exist = cache.get(key);
            if(!exist.contains(id)) {                
                exist.add(id);
            }                
        } else {
            Set<String> _e = new HashSet<String>();
            _e.add(id);
            this.cache.put(key, _e);
        }

    }        
}
```

output
1 h
1 ho
1 hou
1 hous
1 house

I was hoping to replace my cache implementation with something like Ehcache, however I'm not very familiar with it. I'm wondering if anybody has any recommendations on setting something like this up so response times on keystrokes would remain 500ms or less.

I seen this page http://ehcache.org/documentation/get-started/getting-started

but perhaps my current populating method is causing me to over look a better approach.

Does anybody have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you look to optimize for performance, have a look at [patricia tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), there is an implementation [here](http://code.google.com/p/patricia-trie/) that implements SortedMap.